# How long should I wait before adding content to a 'moved' website?

Tags: google-search-console, content, migration

I 'moved' my website from domain A to domain B. Did all the necessary things (301, notified Google in Webmaster Tools).

The question is, how long should I wait until I can put new content on domain A?

Comment: You moved the domain A to domain B to use the domain A for another website, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The old content won't be there anymore. I could create 301 for the old pages though.

Comment: As long as you do not have any URL/URI and potential file name conflicts, you should be okay now. I would not wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the domain A right now if you want.

The only issue you can think about is URLs which already existed on your old site on domain A because users could be redirected to the domain B. Make sure you don't have duplicated URLs between your new site and the old one on the domain A.

Comment: And what should I do with the entry of the old site A in Google webmaster tools? It's flagged as 'change of address submitted'.  Shouldn't I cancel that 'change of address' eventually?

Comment: As long as you have the 301-redirects working, you can delete the domain A from Webmaster Tools and add it again for the new site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new domain right away. Trust Google to index it anew properly. Just make sure you have done Change of Address in Google Webmasters Tools. That way Google knows its you and transfers the 'trust metric' to your new domain. The SEO will be handled well enough if you have a 301 configured properly.